# Machine Learning/Text Analysis/Algorithm Pointers

Tags: machine-learning, r, algorithms, learning

I'm looking for a reference or point in the right direction since I'm not too familiar with machine learning or algorithms. I'd prefer to work in R, but I could also do Python. Any reference to a specific package I could use would be great.

So I have a list of Senate bills and their descriptions that are one or two sentences long. I have a subset of bills that also have accompanied bill types (ie "budget", "immigration", etc). I want to create an algorithm that will assign a bill type(s) to the other subset of bills that don't have bill types.

I would want to be able to do this by using the underlying relationship between descriptions and bill types for the first subset and apply it to the second so that I can predict bill type from bill description. Does this make sense? Any advice would be welcome!

Comment: This problem is called _document classification_.

Comment: How many examples of each type of bill do you have?  All of Pythinker's advice is good, but if your dataset is small it might be tough to train (and you'd definitely want to use an existing word2vec representation in that case).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, This absolutely makes sense. This is a common NLP (Natural Language Processing) problem. You should use word embedding models alingside LSTM (Long Short Term Memory) and deep neural networks. Actually, first you should represent every word as a vector of fixed dimension (e.g. 100) using word2vec. Then you should build a deep neural network architecture. The inputs of this network are your word vectors for each bill that are concatenated to form a sequence of vectors. The output of this network is a label that indicate which type of bill you are considering. I highly recommend that you use ***Keras*** which is a great python package for dealing with deep learning and NLP. Also, you can use existing word2vec sets that contain vector representations of most of words of a language (e.g. English). For example you can use GoogleNews word2vec set.